# Can dask do something similar to pandas merge_asof?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I notice merge_asof is mentioned in the API (http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html) but does not appear to be implemented.

The code for merge in dataframe.methods is trivial, so I could imagine just copying that for merge_asof, but I'm very new to the library and have no idea what effect that would have.

Finally, I could imagine doing it using reindex, but that dosn't appear to be implemented either... although I do see ffill is in the API reference as well.

Any guidance would be apprciated!

Comment: As of December 2016, merge_asof is not implemented in dask.dataframe.  The mentions in docstrings are due to https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1815

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. Is there any way I can implement similar functionality for myself? (couple possibilities mentioned in the question)

Comment: I recommend looking at the code in dask/dataframe/multi.py

Comment: I really appreciate the support. I now gather that the issue with something like a reindex would be that we might have to fill forward from a different partition, whereas dask prefers to line up partitions directly and do normal data frame operations on them. Is that about right? In that case, it might make the most sense for me to manually partition my frames into chunks I know will be comparable, use straight pandas on those, and then recombine to a dask frame. Is that about right?